# How to merge two vectors of type pandas.core.series.Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two vectors of type pandas.core.series.Series. How can I merge the two like two columns? Using pd.concat(X,Y) or pd.merge(X,Y) both give me TypeErrors.

```
In [159]: X
Out[159]:
0       11.896552
1        0.360488
2        2.244628
3        0.109661
4        6.447692
5        0.431621
6        0.320261
7        0.574196
8        0.585305
9        0.144247
10       0.104566
11       0.400604
12       0.296167
13       1.691785
14       0.299039
15       0.224044
16       0.328581
17       3.955307
18       0.053480
19       0.525418
20       1.349805
21       6.247086
22       1.031546
23       1.000634
24       1.234226
25       0.069274
26       0.656316
27       9.957547
28       0.787225
29    8505.000000
30      14.927928
dtype: float64

In [160]: Y
Out[160]:
0          NaN
1     0.003629
2     0.014316
3     0.008848
4    -0.070776
5    -0.010462
6    -0.021063
7    -0.001017
8    -0.023812
9     0.025068
10   -0.004910
11    0.032937
12   -0.010832
13    0.070146
14   -0.027833
15    0.023993
16    0.014792
17   -0.006672
18    0.008040
19    0.005141
20    0.015845
21    0.008013
22    0.002213
23   -0.010444
24    0.002137
25    0.001358
26    0.034552
27    0.111516
28    0.006442
29   -0.022038
30    0.014333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You can indeed use both ```concat``` and ```merge```. Check out [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-combine-two-series-into-dataframe/#:~:text=Combine%20Two%20Series%20Using%20pandas.,-merge()&text=merge()%20can%20be%20used,True%2C%20left_index%3DTrue) link.

Answer (score 0):

For concatenation, you need to include squared brackets in your function call and specify the axis.

```
X, Y = pd.Series(range(0,10), name='X'), pd.Series(range(10,20), name='Y')
X_Y_concat = pd.concat([X, Y], axis=1)
```

For merging, you need to specify to merge on the index.

```
X_Y_merged = pd.merge(X, Y, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Both function calls return a `pd.DataFrame`.